# Delete 10 characters from cell to left in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have to run =LEFT(x, len(x)-10) in Excel all the time (and then do some finding/replacing and cell formatting); however the cell I need to run the formula on always changes, so I haven't been able to successfully record a macro to save time.

Can I change that formula to reference *the cell to the left*, and not the **specific** cell address? That way as long as I have the right cell selected, I could record a macro to do it all for me automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula:

```
=LEFT(INDEX($1:$1048576,row(),column()-1),LEN(INDEX($1:$1048576,row(),column()-1))-10)
```

vba:

```
Sub tryThis()
    Selection = Left(Selection.Offset(,-1),Len(Selection.Offset(,-1))-10)
End Sub
```

Comment: When I use this and try the macro on a different sheet or different column, it still tries to run it on the column from the recording, not the column I'm working on (I recorded using E1 but want to run the macro on S1, for instance). Maybe I'm misunderstanding this more than I initially thought...

Comment: The recorder will always lock the cell reference,  You want to use the one line of code I gave you.  It will be based on the selected cell.  There should not be any other code.